# OCaml error an expression was expected of type int (confusing error)

Tags: types, type-conversion, ocaml, ocamlbuild

My code:

```
let safe_log10 = function x -> if (x <= 0.) then None else Some (log10 x);;
```

With input `-1.0`, this gives:

```
safe_log10 -1.0;;
Error: This expression has type float -> float option
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

However, it works fine with `(-1.0)`:

```
# safe_log10 (-1.0);;
- : float option = None
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix the function to work for `safe_log10 -1.0`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that `-` and `1.0` are written together, this `-` is still a binary operator, and your expression looks like `function - float`, which doesn't make sense. In OCaml, unlike many other languages, binary `-` can only be applied to `int` and `int`; even for floats you need a different operator `-.`.